# How to launch some links in particular browser using slickrun

Tags: firefox, google-chrome

How to specify the command parameter in slick run to launch a specific link in chrome or IE or firefox.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of including the website link in the "Filename" field, type the link in "parameters" field. In the "filename" field give the browser details such as "chrome" for google chrome, "iexplore" for IE.

Answer (score 5):

The 'Filename' field should contain the application that you wish to run (e.g.  firefox, chrome, iexplore).  You can then specify the URL that you want to open in the 'Parameters' field.

[image]

If you wish to open more than one URL then please see the following page for details:  http://boontlee.blogspot.co.uk/2009/01/slickrun-opening-multiple-sites-with.html